# MySQL Inserting data from other tables - auto increment skips

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have an empty "new_table" and "old_1" + "old_2" tables. 
When I insert 3000 rows from old_1 to new_table everything is fine.

But when I insert data from old_2 table, auto_increment id's starts from ~4000, not from 3000.. Any ideas why this is happening? I would like to have the new rows starting from 3001.

```
INSERT INTO new_table ( col1,col2,col3 ) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM old_1;
INSERT INTO new_table ( col1,col2,col3 ) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM old_2;
```

EDIT: I havent deleted any rows or messed with auto_increment values at all. I just ran 2 queries in a row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: Thank you Peter for reply, but that doesnt explain why the auto increment number skips and how to insert the new rows without skipping =/

Comment: True, but there are other posts about that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668369/why-does-mysql-skip-some-auto-increment-ids

Comment: check your auto_increment_offset value after inserting first table data if it is showing like 4000 then alter table with auto_increment value as 3001 and then insert other table data.

Comment: What is the DDL for the table where you insert?