# What is the best practice to update 2 million rows data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

What is the best practice to update 2 million rows data in MySQL?
As update by primary id, I have to update 1 by 1. It is so slow. 
Like below

```
UPDATE table SET col1=value1 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE table SET col1=value2 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE table SET col1=value3 WHERE id=3;

UPDATE table SET col1=valueN WHERE id=N;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table is innodb (look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output) one of the reasons its slow is an insufficient `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

I also assume its in the default `auto_commit=1` mode meaning each SQL line is a single transaction.

Its generally best to avoid processes that need to change every row in a table.

You could split this into a number of threads doing updates and that should get though the list quicker. If the table is MyISAM it won't scale this way.

Answer (score 0):

Good way to update many rows in one query with `INSERT` statement with condition `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The statement will update the old row if there is a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY. [See documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```sql
INSERT INTO table (id, col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    col1 = VALUES(col1), 
    col2 = VALUES(col2), 
    col3 = VALUES(col3);
```

To update really big amount of date like 2 millions rows try to separate you data to several queries by several thousand rows.

Also notice optimization tips: [Optimizing INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html) and [Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but if you have an auto_increment column (id) you might quickly reach its upper limit, because the storage engine increases the auto_increment even on "ON DUPLICATE" value found - "The storage engine must increment the AUTO_INCREMENT value before inserting a row. It does not know if the insert will fail yet at that point. " - more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087869/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-update-adds-one-to-the-autoincrement