# in PHP, confused about MySQL input for new and returning users, when email is a UNIQUE field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a PHP and MySQL newbie, and the behavior of mysql_insert_id() has become a brick wall for me when one of the database fields is UNIQUE. Greatly simplified, I have 2 tables.

**property table**

PropertyID  PK, AI

//many property descriptors

UserID FK to user table

**user table**

UserID  PK, AI

email  UNIQUE

password

After validation, I insert the user's email into the users table and see if the email is already present, and thus a returning user. If not present, it is inserted and is a new user.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user ( email ) VALUES ( '$email' )";
//INSERT to a UNIQUE email causes an error & abort. With IGNORE, no INSERT happens (affected_rows=0)
$UserID = mysql_insert_id(); // is 0 if email exists in its UNIQUE field
if ( mysql_affected_rows() == 0 ) {//0 is existing user, else is new user}
```

This works fine to separate new and returning users, who get different messages later. And it sets up 2 logic channels - one to input the new password, and the second to check if the input password matches.

However, the UserID of a second entry by a user (or third, and beyond) is always 0, zero because the email field is UNIQUE. Thus I can't make useful queries in the property table against UserID because all returning user rows have UserID=0

Despite a lot of searching, I haven't found or figured out a solution.  How can I get the real UserID, not the 0 return, into the property table for both new and returning users?

Try to be specific with responses. I don't follow general directions well in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from this question/answer - [getting mysql_insert_id() while using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634152/getting-mysql-insert-id-while-using-on-duplicate-key-update-with-php)

Try changing from `INSERT IGNORE` to `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user ( email ) VALUES ( '$email' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) ";
```

Using `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` will then get the `id` of the returning user in `mysql_insert_id()`.

mysql docs -
[`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
, [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Works like a charm on the 1st try. Thanks so much.  I had found and tried LAST_INSERT_ID(), but somehow I did not use it correctly. Thanks for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user ( email ) VALUES ( '$email' )";
mysql_query($sql);
//INSERT to a UNIQUE email causes an error & abort. With IGNORE, no INSERT happens   (affected_rows=0)
$UserID = mysql_insert_id(); // is 0 if email exists in its UNIQUE field

if($UserID==0) //no insert
{
  $email = mysql_real_scape_string($email);
  $sql = "select * from user where email = '$email'"; //check for user on table user
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $UserID = $row['UserID']; //return the user id that matches de email
}
```

PS: **Use mysql or PDO**...the mysql extension it's on the process to become deprecated....try mysqli extension...the procedural way of mysqli it's very similar to the way you use mysql extension on PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my problem. The other solution gets the job done with just one trip through the database.