# MySQL: Get results.insertId ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am developing an application that downloads images and their tags. When a download starts the program retrieves the tags and inserts them into the database. Here I am trying to insert a new tag and then create a relationship between the the tag and its download. The combination of name and type in tag is unique.

```
let download_id = 1;
let tag = {type:'language', name:'english'}

let sql = `INSERT INTO tag (name, type) SELECT '${tag.name}', id FROM tag_type WHERE type='${tag.type}' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1, id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`
mysqlConnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO download_tag ?`;
    mysqlConnection.query(sql, [{download_id: download_id, tag_id: results.insertId}], err => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

However my first query returns this error `Uncaught Error: ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous` I am unsure why my code is not working, it is very similar to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634152/getting-mysql-insert-id-while-using-on-duplicate-key-update-with-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `LAST_INSERT_ID` doesn't know whether you are referring to `id` from the `tag` table or from the `tag_type` table. You just need to qualify the field name with its table:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO tag (name, type)
           SELECT '${tag.name}', id FROM tag_type WHERE type='${tag.type}' 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1, id=LAST_INSERT_ID(tag.id)`
```